# Undefined local variable or method `new_prepodavatels_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem: After starting server I got this error:
undefined local variable or method `prepodavatels_stats_path' for #<#:0x0000000461ec58> I presented rake routes in this post.

Error on the following line

```
<li><%= link_to "", prepodavatels_stats_path %><li>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :prepodavatels do
    collection do
      get 'stats'
    end
    resources :predmets
    resources :ppdatas
end
```

rake routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                    Controller#Action
             groups GET    /groups(.:format)                              groups#index
                    POST   /groups(.:format)                              groups#create
          new_group GET    /groups/new(.:format)                          groups#new
         edit_group GET    /groups/:id/edit(.:format)                     groups#edit
              group GET    /groups/:id(.:format)                          groups#show
                    PATCH  /groups/:id(.:format)                          groups#update
                    PUT    /groups/:id(.:format)                          groups#update
                    DELETE /groups/:id(.:format)                          groups#destroy
    students_index2 GET    /students/index2(.:format)                     students#index2
    students_index3 GET    /students/index3(.:format)                     students#index3
    students_index4 GET    /students/index4(.:format)                     students#index4
    students_index5 GET    /students/index5(.:format)                     students#index5
    students_index6 GET    /students/index6(.:format)                     students#index6
     stats_students GET    /students/stats(.:format)                      students#stats
           students GET    /students(.:format)                            students#index
                    POST   /students(.:format)                            students#create
        new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)                        students#new
       edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)                   students#edit
            student GET    /students/:id(.:format)                        students#show
                    PATCH  /students/:id(.:format)                        students#update
                    PUT    /students/:id(.:format)                        students#update
                    DELETE /students/:id(.:format)                        students#destroy
stats_prepodavatels GET    /prepodavatels/stats(.:format)                 prepodavatels#stats
           predmets GET    /prepodavatels/predmets(.:format)              predmets#index
                    POST   /prepodavatels/predmets(.:format)              predmets#create
        new_predmet GET    /prepodavatels/predmets/new(.:format)          predmets#new
       edit_predmet GET    /prepodavatels/predmets/:id/edit(.:format)     predmets#edit
            predmet GET    /prepodavatels/predmets/:id(.:format)          predmets#show
                    PATCH  /prepodavatels/predmets/:id(.:format)          predmets#update
                    PUT    /prepodavatels/predmets/:id(.:format)          predmets#update
                    DELETE /prepodavatels/predmets/:id(.:format)          predmets#destroy
            ppdatas GET    /prepodavatels/ppdatas(.:format)               ppdatas#index
                    POST   /prepodavatels/ppdatas(.:format)               ppdatas#create
         new_ppdata GET    /prepodavatels/ppdatas/new(.:format)           ppdatas#new
        edit_ppdata GET    /prepodavatels/ppdatas/:id/edit(.:format)      ppdatas#edit
             ppdata GET    /prepodavatels/ppdatas/:id(.:format)           ppdatas#show
                    PATCH  /prepodavatels/ppdatas/:id(.:format)           ppdatas#update
                    PUT    /prepodavatels/ppdatas/:id(.:format)           ppdatas#update
                    DELETE /prepodavatels/ppdatas/:id(.:format)           ppdatas#destroy
      prepodavatels GET    /prepodavatels(.:format)                       prepodavatels#index
                    POST   /prepodavatels(.:format)                       prepodavatels#create
   new_prepodavatel GET    /prepodavatels/new(.:format)                   prepodavatels#new
  edit_prepodavatel GET    /prepodavatels/:id/edit(.:format)              prepodavatels#edit
       prepodavatel GET    /prepodavatels/:id(.:format)                   prepodavatels#show
                    PATCH  /prepodavatels/:id(.:format)                   prepodavatels#update
                    PUT    /prepodavatels/:id(.:format)                   prepodavatels#update
                    DELETE /prepodavatels/:id(.:format)                   prepodavatels#destroy
              admin GET    /admin(.:format)                               admin#index
        admin_index GET    /admin/index(.:format)                         admin#index
      ppdatas_index GET    /ppdatas/index(.:format)                       ppdatas#index
     ppdatas_index2 GET    /ppdatas/index2(.:format)                      ppdatas#index2
index2_year_courses PATCH  /year_courses/index2(.:format)                 year_courses#index2
       year_courses GET    /year_courses(.:format)                        year_courses#index
                    POST   /year_courses(.:format)                        year_courses#create
    new_year_course GET    /year_courses/new(.:format)                    year_courses#new
   edit_year_course GET    /year_courses/:id/edit(.:format)               year_courses#edit
        year_course GET    /year_courses/:id(.:format)                    year_courses#show
                    PATCH  /year_courses/:id(.:format)                    year_courses#update
                    PUT    /year_courses/:id(.:format)                    year_courses#update
                    DELETE /year_courses/:id(.:format)                    year_courses#destroy
          group_new GET    /groups/:group_id/new(.:format)                groups#new
         group_show GET    /groups/:group_id/show(.:format)               groups#show
                    PATCH  /groups/index(.:format)                        groups#index
                    PATCH  /groups/new(.:format)                          groups#new
       _form_groups PATCH  /groups/_form(.:format)                        groups#_form
                    PATCH  /groups/show(.:format)                         groups#show
                    GET    /groups(.:format)                              groups#index
                    POST   /groups(.:format)                              groups#create
                    GET    /groups/new(.:format)                          groups#new
                    GET    /groups/:id/edit(.:format)                     groups#edit
                    GET    /groups/:id(.:format)                          groups#show
                    PATCH  /groups/:id(.:format)                          groups#update
                    PUT    /groups/:id(.:format)                          groups#update
                    DELETE /groups/:id(.:format)                          groups#destroy
                    GET    /students/index2(.:format)                     students#index2
                    GET    /students/index3(.:format)                     students#index3
                    GET    /students/index4(.:format)                     students#index4
                    GET    /students/index5(.:format)                     students#index5
                    GET    /students/index6(.:format)                     students#index6
     students_stats GET    /students/stats(.:format)                      students#stats
              login GET    /login(.:format)                               sessions#new
                    POST   /login(.:format)                               sessions#create
             logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                              sessions#destroy
           ppdatas3 GET    /ppdatas/index3(.:format)                      ppdatas#index3
           ppdatas2 GET    /ppdatas/index2(.:format)                      ppdatas#index2
       sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                        sessions#new
    sessions_create GET    /sessions/create(.:format)                     sessions#create
   sessions_destroy GET    /sessions/destroy(.:format)                    sessions#destroy
              users GET    /users(.:format)                               users#index
                    POST   /users(.:format)                               users#create
           new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                           users#new
          edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                      users#edit
               user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                           users#show
                    PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                           users#update
                    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                           users#update
                    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                           users#destroy
                    GET    /ppdatas(.:format)                             ppdatas#index
                    POST   /ppdatas(.:format)                             ppdatas#create
                    GET    /ppdatas/new(.:format)                         ppdatas#new
                    GET    /ppdatas/:id/edit(.:format)                    ppdatas#edit
                    GET    /ppdatas/:id(.:format)                         ppdatas#show
                    PATCH  /ppdatas/:id(.:format)                         ppdatas#update
                    PUT    /ppdatas/:id(.:format)                         ppdatas#update
                    DELETE /ppdatas/:id(.:format)                         ppdatas#destroy
                    GET    /students(.:format)                            students#index
                    POST   /students(.:format)                            students#create
                    GET    /students/new(.:format)                        students#new
                    GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)                   students#edit
                    GET    /students/:id(.:format)                        students#show
                    PATCH  /students/:id(.:format)                        students#update
                    PUT    /students/:id(.:format)                        students#update
                    DELETE /students/:id(.:format)                        students#destroy
       course_years GET    /courses/:course_id/years(.:format)            years#index
                    POST   /courses/:course_id/years(.:format)            years#create
    new_course_year GET    /courses/:course_id/years/new(.:format)        years#new
   edit_course_year GET    /courses/:course_id/years/:id/edit(.:format)   years#edit
        course_year GET    /courses/:course_id/years/:id(.:format)        years#show
                    PATCH  /courses/:course_id/years/:id(.:format)        years#update
                    PUT    /courses/:course_id/years/:id(.:format)        years#update
                    DELETE /courses/:course_id/years/:id(.:format)        years#destroy
     course_courses GET    /courses/:course_id/courses(.:format)          courses#index
                    POST   /courses/:course_id/courses(.:format)          courses#create
  new_course_course GET    /courses/:course_id/courses/new(.:format)      courses#new
 edit_course_course GET    /courses/:course_id/courses/:id/edit(.:format) courses#edit
      course_course GET    /courses/:course_id/courses/:id(.:format)      courses#show
                    PATCH  /courses/:course_id/courses/:id(.:format)      courses#update
                    PUT    /courses/:course_id/courses/:id(.:format)      courses#update
                    DELETE /courses/:course_id/courses/:id(.:format)      courses#destroy
            courses GET    /courses(.:format)                             courses#index
                    POST   /courses(.:format)                             courses#create
         new_course GET    /courses/new(.:format)                         courses#new
        edit_course GET    /courses/:id/edit(.:format)                    courses#edit
             course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#show
                    PATCH  /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#update
                    PUT    /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#update
                    DELETE /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#destroy
                    GET    /predmets(.:format)                            predmets#index
                    POST   /predmets(.:format)                            predmets#create
                    GET    /predmets/new(.:format)                        predmets#new
                    GET    /predmets/:id/edit(.:format)                   predmets#edit
                    GET    /predmets/:id(.:format)                        predmets#show
                    PATCH  /predmets/:id(.:format)                        predmets#update
                    PUT    /predmets/:id(.:format)                        predmets#update
                    DELETE /predmets/:id(.:format)                        predmets#destroy
              years GET    /years(.:format)                               years#index
                    POST   /years(.:format)                               years#create
           new_year GET    /years/new(.:format)                           years#new
          edit_year GET    /years/:id/edit(.:format)                      years#edit
               year GET    /years/:id(.:format)                           years#show
                    PATCH  /years/:id(.:format)                           years#update
                    PUT    /years/:id(.:format)                           years#update
                    DELETE /years/:id(.:format)                           years#destroy
```

Comment: Post your full error stack.

Comment: Post your `rake routes output`

Comment: OK. I presented rake routes

Comment: That `link_to` code snippet belongs to which file?

Comment: application.html.erb P.S. students_stats - is work but prepodavatels_stats is not work

Comment: <li><%= link_to stats_prepodavatels_path %><li> - this code is work, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<li><%= link_to stats_prepodavatels_path %><li>
```

Does this work?

Comment: I had a similar issue with my routes I had user_home_path named route inside routes.rb and this produced error,  with your answer I added one more _path and worked. So this returns undefined method error 'user_home_path' but when I write as 'user_home_path_path'    it worked!   Thank you! (btw I updated name to this route to only one _path :d)